# golang file name too long error when reading from os.Args[1]

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and using `ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])` to fetch a file path from the cli and then processing each line using:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main()  {
    
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Now I can get the output at stdout. But also get the following ERROR in the end:

```
msg:"BRUMBRUM";reference:cve,CVE-2007-2810;reference:blah;
msg:"WAKANDA";reference:cve,CVE-2007-2810;reference:blah; file name too long
exit status 1
```

My file path input is `data/srulz.tcl`
. FYI, the error message is not a part of the text file.

I need to know where is this going wrong here and how can this be improved?

> UPDATE:
>
> **Provided issue reproducible code.**
>
> Go-ing with flag pkg for now until this mystery is solved

Comment: Maybe that error message is part of `data/srulz.tcl`? Or the error comes from other code you don't show us..

Comment: Is that error message anything that your program actually prints? Is it possible that that text is in the file?

Comment: The error message is not in the text file - the last line is just not empty.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The info in the question is not enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: @icza I've updated the code now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, 
filePath, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])

Above step will read the whole file contents and return slice of byte and error. filePath variable will not store the file path instead its storing the content of file in bytes. I am wondering why are you not getting compile time error as filepath variable is slice of bytes whereas  os.Open(filepath) the argument to os.Open will be string.